# Fix link formatting when automatically modify a trivial answer to a comment

Tags: feature-request, links, comments

When you answer a trivial answer (I'm not sure what qualify an answer to be trivial but I would guess that it depends on the words count), the answer is changed automatically to a comment, but if you have formatted urls in the answer, they won't be formatted in the comment. Can we format the links in the comment if they were formatted in the answer?